# js Variable for calling a function without ()

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how to do something like this without needing the ():

```
let start = () => document.getElementById("#start");
```

currently i use it like this:

```
start().classList.remove("hidden");
```

but i would like to use it like this:

```
start.classList.remove("hidden");
```

but it should still call the function. How do I do this?

Comment: "*but it should still call the function.*" sounds like you're having a problem with defining the variable too early. The whole "needing to call the function without ()" sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there are any *good* ways to do this, but there are a few ugly and not recommended ways.

- You could rely on the fact that [DOM elements with IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables) automatically become global variables, and not use `getElementById` at all:

  ```
  start.classList.remove("hidden");
  ```
- You could make `window.start` a getter:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'start', { get() { return document.getElementById("start"); } });

start.classList.remove("hidden");
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="start" class="hidden">foo</div>
```

- You could use `with` and a getter (please don't do this):

```js
with ({
  get start() { return document.getElementById("start"); }
}) {
  start.classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="start" class="hidden">foo</div>
```

If `start` happened to be part of an object, rather than referencing it as a standalone variable, putting a getter on the object would be a much more reasonable solution:

```js
const domElements = {
  get start() { return document.getElementById("start"); }
};
domElements.start.classList.remove("hidden");
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="start" class="hidden">foo</div>
```

Comment: It (1) requires global pollution (which is inelegant and can lead to bugs) (2) is somewhat unintuitive - a script reader normally wouldn't expect simply *referencing* an identifier to possibly result in side-effects (like the running of arbitrary code)